# Why alexa doesn't crawl my site?

Tags: seo, alexa

I was waiting for already 1 week and alexa still not recognize my site. I already put a robot.txt in my site. Locating in www.mydomain.com/robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Please suggest why this happening, Thanks.

Comment: A week isn't very long to wait for a search engine to notice your site.  Especially if it's new, and especially if there aren't many links to it yet.

Comment: Are you being indexed by anything? Your Robots.txt file says "All agents, ignore everything from / on down."

Answer (score 3):

You disallow everything.

my robots.txt looks like:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

and i'm getting crawled just fine (although i don't know what alexa is).

Answer (score 2):

Don't follow the advice above: `allow:/` is NOT the way to go. If you want all crawlers to access your site you want to use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```